# How create new model without required fields and validation rules?

Tags: validation, yii, model, yii2

In my form there are 2 models. The activity of second one depends on select in one of the dropdowns. If I not choose the right one I don't won't to use validation required fields of second model.

For example...

```
$modelOne = new ModelOne;
$modelTwo = new ModelTwo; 

.... 

    if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
     .... 
    } else {
         return $this->render('create', [
                     'model' => $model,
                ]);
    }
```

I'am wondering if there is some options when creating model to remove validations and required fields.

Like,

```
modelTwo = new modelTwo([ *something that removes validation* ]);
```

I tried with scenarios, but than cant load inputs in `modelTwo->load(Yii::$app->request->post());`

Comment: Check [conditional validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation)

Comment: Not the right solution. Becouse I want to remove required fields not to add a new one. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What? What do you mean by "add a new one"?

Comment: When I add conditional validation, the required fields still are required.

Comment: Only when condition is met - isn't this something you want?

Comment: I want model without required fileds. Just that

Comment: remove the rules from the rules function which has required validation for the fields

Comment: That's not the point...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to validate your model when saving just use $model->save(false).

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail

Comment: When I create new model, I create it with rules on and I'm rendering it on the page with rules. I can't do submit becouse of error messages

Comment: Then don't use activeform for those fields or just disable the validation on them